# Extracting plot from notebook

Tags: animation

I'm trying to save animations in [this](https://blog.wolfram.com/2011/03/18/built-to-last-understanding-earthquake-engineering/) notebook as a gif, but when I try to save them or create a new notebook it saves a blank image. How can I extract the code which creates these animations?

Comment: Do you mean from the corresponding CDF-file?

Comment: yes. How do you do that?

Comment: Inspect CDF with a text editor. You will see it consists of several `Cell[]` or `CellGroupData[]` commands. So, you can just select a range of your interest, paste in notebook as `CellPrint@<here pasted code>`, evaluate that and you will see the code to produce desired `Manipulate` like : `With[{...}, Manipulate[...]]`. Further steps are simple: change `Manipulate` to `Table`, get rid of `Dynamic`, set desired step (of manipulated varuable), and `Export` this `Table` to gif.

Comment: @rodger_kicks, The animation in CDF is not a trivial image sequence. Thus, you can't save it as gif directly. You need parse the cdf to find the source data for animation, evaluate it making graphics and save the gif.